# PTIJ: The girl who cried wolf

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Does Aesop's story about [The Boy Who Cried Wolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_Who_Cried_Wolf) actually originate from Miriam Bas Bilgah, the girl who cried wolf ([Sukkah 56b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.56b.5))? Miriam accused the altar of being a "wolf", consuming Korbanos.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).